# Does the Euler-Lagrange functional actually have a functional derivative?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, gateaux-derivative

It's well known that given a functional $$S(\boldsymbol q) = \int_a^b L(t,\boldsymbol q(t),\dot{\boldsymbol q}(t))\, \mathrm{d}t,$$
the directional (or otherwise known as the Gateaux) derivative
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{S(\boldsymbol q + \epsilon \boldsymbol \phi) - S(\boldsymbol q)}{\epsilon}$$
can be expressed as an integral $$\int_a^b \mathrm dt\,\phi(t)\cdot(L_x(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t))-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}L_v(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t)))$$
only when $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$, otherwise this integral expression doesn't work. But in general, if a functional $F$ has a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative), then the Gateaux derivative $dF(q;\phi)$ of $F$ has to be expressible as an inner product of $\phi$ with the functional derivative of $F$ at $q$. In which case, does the functional derivative of $S$ actually exist? It seems not to, as it requires the condition that $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$.

Comment: It's a matter of specifying domains; $S$ acts on functions satisfying the Dirichlet BC only, and so its derivative admits only directions that vanish at the boundary.

Comment: @Ian That makes sense

Comment: However if you want to enlarge the domain, then you must accept that the boundary terms will appear in the expression for the functional derivative, whereas they vanish in the usual procedure for deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation. In that respect the functional derivative is a linear mapping on a suitable space which doesn't have a "Riesz representation".

Comment: @Ian If the domain is larger, does that imply that the functional derivative involves Dirac delta impulses centred at the boundary?

Comment: In order to represent it as a "function" that you "take the inner product with", yes. That's what I meant by the lack of a "Riesz representation".

Comment: @Ian I see, thanks. I understand now